# is this code for parsing from string method to integer answer ok?

Tags: java, parsing

So I'm making a programme in java for a college assignment.

in my main menu i have a choice option that a user can choose from 1-7 and to validate that I created this

```
public static String validateChoice(int floor, int roof) { // method for validating user input. floor = lowest possible value user can input & roof is maximum possible value user can input
    int choice = -1;
    String errorMessage = "Error: only numbers between " + floor + " and " + roof + " are accepted";

    while(true) { // keeps looping until valid choice number is met
        while(!intScanner.hasNextInt()) { // will keep looping if user doesn't input an int e.g user inputs string
            intScanner.next(); // if user inputs string then eat that up and print error message and loop again
            System.out.println(errorMessage);
        }
        choice = intScanner.nextInt(); 

        if(choice >= floor && choice <= roof) // if choice is inbetween floor and roof 
            return Integer.toString(choice); // return that value parsed as a string (cause this method is string)
        else
            System.out.println(errorMessage);

    }
}
            System.out.println(errorMessage);
```

and that is returned into this

```
choice = Integer.parseInt(validateChoice(floor, roof));
```

My question is, is it ok to parse from a string method to an int variable. I'll admit i'm fairly ignorant in java so I would like your opinions on whether it's a good idea to write programmes like that. My thought process was is like it's two birds with one stone. It validates ints and returns an error when user input is wrong in one method

Comment: Why convert your `int` to a `String` only to parse it back to an `int` right afterwards?

Comment: because if a user inputs a string it'll print an error message but if they enter an int then i store that and if the int is between the floor and roof then i return it as a string because of the string method ( i have the string method to print error messages ) and that goes back into a variable called choice which is then used to select what options are available in the menu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a poor idea, just return the `int`. Converting to a `String` isn't free. Parsing a `String` back to an `int` isn't free, and your method could easily return an `int`.

As I said, just return the `int`.

```
public static int validateChoice(int floor, int roof) {
    String errorMessage = "Error: only numbers between " + floor 
            + " and " + roof + " are accepted";
    while (true) {
        while (!intScanner.hasNextInt()) {
            intScanner.next();
            System.out.println(errorMessage);
        }
        int choice = intScanner.nextInt();
        if (choice >= floor && choice <= roof) {
            return choice;
        }
        System.out.println(errorMessage);
    }
}
```

And then, to use it,

```
choice = validateChoice(floor, roof);
```

Comment: ah i assumed parsing multiple times would be inefficient. If you don't mind me asking what would your approach be

Comment: I really am an idiot. I was under the impression that you couldn't display string types in an int method. I apologize for my ignorance and thank you for your help